# Collectionview edgeInsets error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

[image]

what can I do? I want change just one row edges.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    if  indexPath.row == 8{
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    }
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: You need to access section, so it should be `if section == 3`

Comment: The parameter given in the method is section, not indexPath.

Answer (score 1):

The `collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAt:` function doesn't set the inset of the cells, but for the section the cells are in. So you don't want to use the `indexPath.row`, because it is irrelevant for that function and therefore doesn't exist. It provides the `section` parameter, which is all that is relevant in that function.

The `section` parameter will contain the value that corresponds to the `indexPath.section` in the other function you posted.

Comment: I understand you but I must access row. Already just one section in my collection view.

Comment: If you want to change the inset for a specific row, then the `insetForSectionAt`-function is the wrong approach. Have you considered removing the inset entirely on the section, and then subtracting the inset of  the other item sizes instead?